# Wolf chasing Sheep in Processing

Tags: processing

I'm currently very new at Processing and just coding in general. I'm trying to make a simple game where I control a wolf with WASD controls. I want to be able to chase the sheep around the canvas but I can't figure out how to make it so that the sheep runs away from the wolf as I'm chasing it. Here's my code

```
Predator[] wolf = new Predator[1];
Prey[] sheep = new Prey[10];

int gameScreen = 0;

void setup()
{
  size(1024, 768);
  frameRate(60);
  
  for(int i = 0; i < sheep.length; i++) {
    sheep[i] = new Prey();
  }
    wolf[0] = new Predator();
    wolf[0].moveSpeed = 3;
}

void draw()
{
  if (gameScreen == 0) {
    initScreen();
  } else if (gameScreen == 1) {
    gameScreen();
  } else if (gameScreen == 2) {
    gameOverScreen();
  }
}

void mousePressed()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < sheep.length; i++) 
  {
     sheep[i].setPosition(random(width), random(height));
  }
  
  wolf[0].setPosition(random(width), random(height));
  
  if (gameScreen==0) 
  {
    startGame();
  }
}

void startGame()
{
  gameScreen = 1;
}

PFont pxlfont;

public float xMove;
public float yMove;

float x, y;
float aimX, aimY;
float noiseOffset=0;
float noiseScale=0.005;

boolean keyW = false;
boolean keyA = false;
boolean keyS = false;
boolean keyD = false;

void initScreen()
{
  pxlfont = loadFont("data/Minecraft.vlw");
  background(181, 220, 114);
  textAlign(CENTER);
  textFont(pxlfont, 50);
  fill(0);
  text("Click to start", width/2, height/2);
}

void gameScreen()
{
  background(181, 220, 114);
  for (int i = 0; i < sheep.length; i++) {
    sheep[i].display();
  }
  
  wolf[0].display();

  if (keyW)
  {
    yMove -= wolf[0].moveSpeed;
  }

  if (keyA)
  {
    xMove -= wolf[0].moveSpeed;
  }

  if (keyS)
  {
    yMove += wolf[0].moveSpeed;
  }

  if (keyD)
  {
    xMove += wolf[0].moveSpeed;
  }
}

void keyPressed()
{
  if (key == 'w')
  {
    keyW = true;
  }

  if (key == 'a')
  {
    keyA = true;
  }

  if (key == 's')
  {
    keyS = true;
  }

  if (key == 'd')
  {
    keyD = true;
  }
}

void keyReleased()
{
  if (key == 'w')
  {
    keyW = false;
  }

  if (key == 'a')
  {
    keyA = false;
  }

  if (key == 's')
  {
    keyS = false;
  }

  if (key == 'd')
  {
    keyD = false;
  }
}

void gameOverScreen()
{
  // codes for game over screen
}

class Predator
{
  PImage wolfImg = loadImage("Images/Wolf.png");

  float x;
  float y;
  float moveSpeed;
  
  void setPosition(float newX, float newY)
  {
    xMove = newX;
    yMove = newY;
  }
  
  // Display
  void display()
  {
    imageMode(CENTER);
    image(wolfImg, xMove, yMove);
  }
}

class Prey
{
  PImage sheepImg = loadImage("Images/Sheep.png");

  float x, y;

  void setPosition(float newX, float newY)
  {
    x = newX;
    y = newY;
  }
  
  // Display
  void display()
  {
    imageMode(CENTER);
    image(sheepImg, x, y);
  }
}
```

So far, I'm only able to move my wolf around with the WASD controls, while the sheep stands still. I'm sorry if my code is a bit messy and not good, I'm still learning. Pls help, thnx :)

Comment: what language is that ?

Comment: This is Processing, it uses Java

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @balu What about reading the tag-info ([tag:processing])? [Processing](https://processing.org/) is a flexible software sketchbook and a language for learning how to code within the context of the visual arts.

Answer (score 0):

To tackle this problem, you need a vector pointing from the predator to the prey and a movement speed for the prey. Instead of separate x and y `float`s, I would use an in-built data type in Processing called `PVector`s.

Here is what I would do:

```
void gameScreen() {
  // all of the other game code

  for (Predator predator : wolf) {
    predator.chase(sheep);
  }
}

class Predator {
   // all the other wolf code

   PVector move = new PVector(0, 0); // making xMove and yMove into one variable (I would add this into the sheep class too)
   
   void chase(Prey[] prey) {
     for (Prey sheep : prey) {
       PVector force = new PVector(x - sheep.x, y - sheep.y).normalize();
       float speed = 5;

       force.mult(speed);

       sheep.move.add(force);

       sheep.move.limit(10); // prevent it from moving too fast
     }
   }
```

Hope this helps!